# Is there a way to get index of clickable in jetpack compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, clickable

So i checked out this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Thp0bB5Ev0&t=73s and i get the Lazycolumn exchange from recyclerview though Philip as he is called uses a column first and says if you do not need a huge list just use column. My question is is it possible to use only column and get the clicked index of the list? my code looks like this.

```
Column() {
    viewModel.settings.forEach { setting ->
        Column(modifies = Modifier.clickable{//can i check thje index here somehow??}) {
            Text(text = setting.name, textAlign = TextAlign.Left, fontSize = 24.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
            Text(text = setting.description, textAlign = TextAlign.Left, fontSize = 12.sp)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [forEachIndexed](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/for-each-indexed.html) in Kotlin you can use:

```
Column() {
viewModel.settings.forEachIndexed { index, setting ->
    Column(modifies = Modifier.clickable{ use the index }) {
        Text(text = setting.name, textAlign = TextAlign.Left, fontSize = 24.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
        Text(text = setting.description, textAlign = TextAlign.Left, fontSize = 12.sp)
        }
    }
}
```